# php, print all rows into <p>

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, pdo

Im trying to print data into a boostrap 3 blockquote and small paragraph.

the blockquoute displays the users comment and the small paragraph displays their name

im using PDO to print all rows with the code below

```
<?php

         $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM review");
         $query->execute();
         $result = $query->fetchAll();

            foreach($result as $row)
        {

      echo "<blockquote>" . $row['brief'] . "</blockquote>";
      echo "<small>" . $row['firstname'] . "</small>";

    }
?>
```

however this code dont display it correctly where as if i do it individually with this code does

```
<blockquote><p><?php print $row['brief'] ?></p><p><small><?php print $row['firstname'] ?></small></p></blockquote>
```

basically the above line is how it looks in HTML but im trying to get the code above to do it automatically

Comment: Define "don't display correctly".  How does it display instead?

Comment: it wasnt putting the firstname in the small tag but echoing as a new p under the blockquote, fix been displayed at bottoms. thanks though

Comment: This question was answered, i have altered my question title- i hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
     echo "<blockquote><p>" . $row['brief']."</p><p>";
     echo "<small>" . $row['firstname'] . "</small>". "</p></blockquote>";
}
```

Comment: with the comments above and you're fix I understand why it wasn't working. and will know this for the future now.

Comment: If this answer was helpfull, dont forget to mark it as correct :)

Comment: could you explain how i could do this please

Answer (score 1):

Where you did it individually, you wrapped the `print` in `<p>`, but not in the `foreach`.

Comment: Also the <blockquote> is closed in a different place in the foreach loop

Comment: thanks guys, with the fix below i understand how it works now, many regards.